# EKS Cluster CoreDNS timeout (20 mins) using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am trying to create a EKS Cluster with Fargate Profile in the AWS environment. However, process is failing after 20 mins during the Core DNS creation. I am just trying to create a Cluster so I can deploy pods in it. I am getting the following error:

[image]

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.0"

  cluster_name    = var.CLUSTER_NAME
  cluster_version = "1.22"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  cluster_enabled_log_types = ["api", "audit", "authenticator", "controllerManager", "scheduler"]

  cluster_addons = {
    kube-proxy = {}
    vpc-cni = {
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
  }

  cluster_encryption_config = [{
    provider_key_arn = aws_kms_key.eks.arn
    resources        = ["secrets"]
  }]

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  # Fargate Profile(s)
  fargate_profiles = {
    coredns-fargate-profile = {
      name = "coredns"
      selectors = [
        {
          namespace = "kube-system"
        },
        {
          namespace = "default"
        },
        {
          namespace = var.ARGOCD_NAME_SPACE
        },
      ]
      pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.pod-execution-role.arn
      service_account_name   = local.k8s_service_account_name
      subnets                = module.vpc.private_subnets
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "coredns" {
  addon_name        = "coredns"
  addon_version     = "v1.8.7-eksbuild.1"
  cluster_name      = var.CLUSTER_NAME
  resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
  depends_on        = [module.eks]
}
```

Comment: I did try with that but ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default the coredns does not run on Fargate but you have requested to run all kube-system workloads on Fargate. Currently, `terraform-aws-eks` does not automatically run coredns on Fargate like `eksctl`.

Try remove the `kube-system` namespace from Fargate profiles and add a node group:

```
...
vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
eks_managed_node_groups = {
   default = {
     ami_type       = "AL2_x86_64"
     instance_types = ["t3.medium"]
     min_size     = 1
     max_size     = 1
     desired_size = 1
   }
}
...
```

After the provision has completed; run the [patch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html#fargate-gs-coredns) command and coredns will then run on Fargate.

Comment: It got stuck again during the creation.

Comment: Is there a node group been created with 1 node is running on the console? Would be good if you can also update your question with the latest code in-used.

Comment: I was missing a node but after adding that node it worked like a charm. Thank you!